# Named Entity recognition in Solr

Tags: mysql, solr, lucene, named-entity-recognition

I am trying to import data in solr from mysql using data import handler, Now I want to identify name entities from it.I am using searchbox(
http://www.searchbox.com/named-entity-recognition-ner-in-solr/). where I am
using stanford ner to identify name entities.

```
<requestHandler name="/dataimport"
class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
<lst name="defaults">
 <str name="config">data-import.xml</str>
 </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

for importing data from mysql and

```
<requestHandler name="/ner" class="com.searchbox.ner.NerHandler" />
  <updateRequestProcessorChain name="mychain" >
   <processor class="com.searchbox.ner.NerProcessorFactory" >
     <lst name="queryFields">
       <str name="queryField">content</str>
     </lst>
   </processor>
   <processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory" />
   <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory" />
 </updateRequestProcessorChain>

 <requestHandler name="/update" class="solr.UpdateRequestHandler">
       <lst name="defaults">
         <str name="update.chain">mychain</str>
       </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

for identifying name entities. NER request handler identifies name entities
from content field, but store extracted entities in solr fields.

NER request handler was working when I am using nutch with solr. But When I
am importing data from mysql, ner request handler is not invoked. So
entities are not stored in solr for imported documents. Can anybody tell me
how to call custom request handler in data import handler.

Otherwise if I can invoke ner request handler externally, so that it can
index person, organization and location in solr for imported document. 
Any suggestion are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure this answers your question but you can specify update chain when you call

```
 /update?update.chain=yourchain
```

([source](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Update+Request+Processors#UpdateRequestProcessors-update.chainrequestparameter)) or make one chain default with

```
<updateRequestProcessorChain name="NERchain" default="true">
```

([source](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateRequestProcessor#Configuring_Update_Request_Processors))